is there a react-native-vision-camera 3.x that works with React Native 0.71?
With RNVC 3.6.4, when I build my app for Android, I get: Execution failed for task ':react-native-vision-camera:buildCMakeRelWithDebInfo[arm64-v8a]'.
I tried deleting node_modules and yarn.lock, then yarn cache clean then yarn install.  (I'm using yarn 1.22.0 in case that makes a difference.)
Can I build with RNVC 3.x and RN 0.71?  If so, what specific version is needed, and are there any extra steps required?
